# Is it possible manipulating timestamp/date in SparkSQL(1.3.0) ?

Tags: date, timestamp, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Since I'm new to Spark (1.3.0), I'm trying to figure out what is possible to do with it, especially Spark SQL.

I'm stuck with timestamp/date formats and I can't pass this obstacle when it comes to operate with these datatypes.

Are there any available operations for these datatypes?

All I can do at the moment is a simple cast from string to timestamp:

```
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  case class Log(visitor: String, visit_date: String, page: String)
  val log = (triple.map(p => Log(p._1,p._2,p._3))).toDF()
  log.registerTempTable("logs")
  val logSessions= sqlContext.sql("SELECT visitor" +
  "                                    ,cast(visit_date as timestamp)" +
  "                                    ,page" +
  "                                FROM logs"
  )
  logSessions.foreach(println)
```

I'm trying to use different "custom SQL" operations on this timestamp (casted from string) but I can't obtain anything but errors.

For example: can I add 30 minutes to my timestamps? How?

Maybe I'm missing something but I can't find any documentation on this topic.

Thanks in advance!

FF

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same thing. Spark 1.5 has added some built in functions:
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html

But for previous versions and something specific looke like  need to implement an UDF.

Comment: thanks a lot for the news Subba... I'll check these new functionalities asap